# How to filter outgoing email to specific address, from Outlook Web App interface?

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

My email server uses Outlook Web App. There is a special account that will be used by a few users (who also know the password), but I am responsible for it. I want to block outgoing email when it is directed to a specific address. I need to do this from the Outlook Web App user's interface, perhaps by implementing a rule or a filter. Is this possible?

I understand that this is a "soft" block, since a knowledgeable user will be able to remove the filter himself. However, at least that is more unlikely, and it will require conscious action. At least accidental email won't be sent to the blocked email addresses.

How can I do this?